# RESTful API Architecture for dynamic searches

Tags: php, api, laravel

I would be interested in some API theory. When I build up the REST Resources, who do you handle such things, like a search by the user for a resource without knowing details. Lets say I got the resource "taxi". So I could build up my API like this:

```
http://api.megataxi.com/v1/taxis
```

to get all taxis in my database. Lets say, the user's app will submit its current position with lat and lng, and I am searching for the nearest taxi around the user. What would be the best practice here? I would have gone for:

```
http://api.megataxi.com/v1/taxis/getTaxisInRange
```

So my routes file would have something like:

```
Route::post('/taxis/getTaxisInRange, 'TaxiCOntroller@getTaxisInRange');
```

but usually I would think the way to go would be done like:

```
http://api.megataxi.com/v1/taxis/list?lat=100&lng=100
```

But how would I reflect something like this in my routes?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part of your question: **how would I reflect something like this in my routes?**

You could do something like this:

```
Route::get('taxis/lat/{lat}/lang/{lng}', function($lat, $lng) { 
    echo 'lat: '. $lat;
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'lng: '. $lng;
});
```

So you could hit the URL like: `taxis/lat/100/lng/100`

Or

```
Route::get('taxis', function() { 
    echo 'lat: '. \Input::get('lat');
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'lng: '. \Input::get('lng');
});
```

which would allow: `taxis?lat=100&lng=100`

If you're subscribed to laracasts.com you should check this out: https://laracasts.com/series/incremental-api-development